# deleting the data after copying it into another database

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure , its contents are as follows:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`MailMe`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_archivev3`()
BEGIN

INSERT INTO 
     send.sgev3_archive(a_bi,
                        b_vc,
                        c_int,
                        d_int,
                        e_vc,
                        f_vc,
                        g_vc,
                        h_vc,
                        i_dt,
                        j_vc,
                        k_vc,
                        l_vc,
                        m_dt,
                        n_vch,
                        o_bit)
SELECT     a_bi,
           b_vc,
           c_int,
           d_int,
           e_vc,
           f_vc,
           g_vc,
           h_vc,
           i_dt,
           j_vc,
           k_vc,
           l_vc,
           m_dt,
           n_vch,
           o_bit

FROM   send.sgev3

WHERE m_dt BETWEEN  '2014-06-09' AND CURDATE();


END
```

Since, my query is inserting the records into `send.sgev3_archive` from `send.sgev3`. I want to do one more thing. I want to delete the records present in the `send.sgev3` table after selecting and inserting the same into `send.sgev3_archive`. Should I write the `DELETE` query right below the SELECT query in my code above? Just wanted to confirm as I don't want to mess up my real data and accidently delete any records without getting it copied. Please advise.

Comment: Especially if `m_dt` is really a timestamp, you shouldn't be using [the inclusive upper-bound of `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  You also need to use the _same value_ for the upper bound in both statements, so you need to get that separately, first.  For that matter, you may wish to be able to pass a range to your stored procedure, not just use a predefined range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes exactly. Include a `DELETE` statement saying

```
DELETE FROM   send.sgev3
WHERE m_dt BETWEEN  '2014-06-09' AND CURDATE();
```

To be more sure that `INSERT` does completes before `DELETE` invokes; wrap the `INSERT` and `DELETE` in a [Transaction Block](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) saying

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO send.sgev3_archive ...
SELECT ... FROM send.sgev3
COMMIT;
```

You can as well handle error condition in your procedure and `ROLLBACK` the entire transaction by using `exit handler in stored procedure`. Below post already shows an way to do the same. Take a look.

[How can I use transactions in my MySQL stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817148/how-can-i-use-transactions-in-my-mysql-stored-procedure)

[MySQL Rollback in transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538436/mysql-rollback-in-transaction)

*EDIT:*

> why transaction is necessary? Can't I just proceed like the way I have
>   mentioned in my question?

Instead of explaining you why; let's show you an example (Quite resemble your scenario)

Let's say you have a table named `parent` declared as

```
create table parent(id int not null auto_increment primary key,
`name` varchar(10),city varchar(10));
```

Insert some records to it

```
insert into parent(`name`,city) values('sfsdfd','sdfsdfdf'),('sfsdfd','sdfsdfdf'),('sfsdfd',null)
```

Now, you have another table named `child` defined as below (Notice the last column has `not null` constraint)

```
create table child(id int not null auto_increment primary key,
`name` varchar(10),city varchar(10) not null)
```

Now execute both the below statement (what you are currently doing)

```
insert into child(`name`,city) select * from parent;
delete from parent;
```

Result: `INSERT` will fail due to the `not null` constraint in `child` table but `delete` will succeed.

To avoid this exact scenario you need `Transaction` in place. so that, if `INSERT` fails you don't go for `delete` at all.

A pseudo code on how you handle this in transaction

```
start transaction

insert into child(`name`,city) select * from parent;

if(ERROR)
rollback
exit from stored proc

else
commit
delete from parent;
```

SideNote: `exit from stored proc` can be implemented using [LEAVE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/leave.html)

Comment: Okay, I will include `DELETE a_bi,b_vc.... `etc after the `SELECT` statement. By the way, on more question, assuming that the stored procedure is gonna run the statements sequentially, it should be running the `INSERT` `STATEMENT` first then `SELECT` and then `DELETE`. Shouldn't it be `SELECT` first and then `INSERT` and then `DELETE`?

Comment: You got it right. It will select the rows and then insert them in `insert into select from`.

Comment: But I am doing opposite in the above query and it is still working as of now without deleting any data(which is obvious as I don't have DELETE command over there). I am wondering why? To be more clear, why my above query is going to run SELECT command first and then Insert it as SELECT command is mentioned below INSERT.

Comment: NO you are not. Read MySQL doc about `insert into select from` to get it clarified.BTW, No Offense but I recall, giving to answer to one of your earlier MySQL event related question; on which you didn't provided any feedback. Just a suggestion: don't do that. If you feel the answer not meeting what you are looking then say so otherwise accept the answer to show your appreciation.

Comment: What is the point of using a separate transaction for each statement?

Comment: @AndriyM, that's an example to let OP know that he can use `trans` to make sure that `insert` gets successful and so pointed him to other post where it's been shown how to handle transaction in stored proc and rollback if needed.

Comment: @rocky: What you've got in your stored procedure is not an INSERT statement *and* a SELECT statement. It's a single INSERT statement, more specifically a variation often referred to as INSERT...SELECT for brevity. (Just think about it: if you remove the SELECT part, what will remain? Just `INSERT INTO tablename (column list)`? That would make no sense, wouldn't it. Therefore, `SELECT ...` in that context is an integral part of the `INSERT` statement.)

Comment: Well, you are showing the syntax but the specific example just makes no sense. That might actually confuse them to a greater extent than educate. The point of declaring an explicit transaction is to make several distinct operations a single atomic operation, in the sense that if one fails, everything is rolled back. In contrast, what you've suggested will allow deletion even if the insert fails.

Comment: Not only would you need to include the `DELETE` in the same transaction, you also need to make sure that `CURDATE()` returns the same value each time; that is, you have to capture it separately, first, then use it in the statements.

Comment: Guys, Thanks for your help. May I know why transaction is necessary? Can't I just proceed like the way I have mentioned in my question?

Comment: @Rahul Why didn't you include `DELETE` in your edited answer of transaction? I mean just before `COMMIT`. Just wondering if there's any reason.

Comment: @rocky, You may want to check the edited answer (mainly the `EDIT:` part) to address your question `why transaction is necessary?`